# Is it cheaper to eat fast food?

Tags: nutrition, economics

I sometimes see claims that poor people become obese and develop "lifestyle diseases" (heart disease, diabetes, etc) because they cannot afford healthy food and are forced to eat fast food.

Logically, this does not seem to make sense.  When you buy fast food, you are paying for labor, corporate overhead, restaurant space, etc.  How could that be cheaper than cooking for yourself?

Comment: 1) I think the common claim is buying read to eat made fast food is cheaper than buying ready to eat "proper food". With a self made food the cost of preparation is hard to compare (value of your own time) 2) Any cost analysis should probably specify what region are you interested about, as the answer will vary wildly depending on that.

Comment: "Cost of time" should be negligible... we are talking about people who either don't work or earn around minimum wage

Comment: "We are talking?" You were talking about "poor", not about "people who either don't work". As for "people earning mininum wage", they can be easily in a sitatuion that they do not have enough time to prepare their meals. Your assumptions seem to me like tied to some particular, but unspecified social background (US?).

Comment: @Suma, what is wrong with my assumption that poor people either don't work or earn a very low wage?  Otherwise they wouldn't be poor, right?  As for not enough time to prepare meals, that seems hard to believe... not enough time for 15 or 20 minutes?  We are not talking about slaves here.

Comment: Not exact duplicate, but to large extend covered by: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4927/are-food-deserts-a-real-phenomenon

Comment: People earning very low wage, even when not slaves, may easily be unable to cook for themselves. When they have 30 minutes for a lunch and no kitchen available (common arrangement in many places), how would they do it?

Comment: @Suma, cook their lunch at home the night before and bring it to work?  Speaking personally, often my lunch is leftovers from the previous day's dinner, so it takes almost no extra time to prepare lunch

Comment: @vartec, please clarify what you mean... it's a little ambiguous... which is cheaper for you, decent food or fast food?

Comment: 1) quality raw ingredients are for different market segment, thus in retail they are quite expensive; 2) to make decent food you need quite a lot of ingredients, most of which don't come in single serving sizes; 3) fast-food can be cheaper because of few reasons: ingredients are not top quality, ingredients are not bought in retail, it's served in large quantities.

Comment: @Blue: for me quality food results more expensive. Ready-to-eat crap from supermarket would cost me something €1/lunch. Just a decent piece of beef cost me like €25/kg, so it's at least €2,50 per (small) serving. Just for the meat, not counting the veggies. Of course I still prefer to eat home food, because I'd rather spend more money and stay healthy.

Comment: @Sk: Why the [tag:united-states] tag?

Comment: OK. It seems I did not convince you your question is not specific enough to be answerable. Can you provide some reference for the claim then, to show it is more notable than "I have heard?" Perhaps the reference will show those hidden assumptions.

Comment: The answer to this question strongly depends on where you live. In Germany, for example, fast-food and highly processed frozen "ready to eat" meals are obscenely cheap when compared to fresh ingredients. The claim is notable when new obesity studies are discussed in the news.

Comment: @Lager: I've got impression it's similar in most of "1st world".

Comment: @vartec: that's an argument I've heard lots of time and which I do not believe. There are plenty of healthy and tasty dishes that do not need super expensive food. Just to make an example, most of the Italian cuisine dishes rely on cheap ingredients, as most of them were originally poor's people food. A nice pasta dish costs less then a fast food meal and takes 15 minutes tops. I think the **real** reason is actually that people can't be bothered to cook.

Comment: @nico: you're right saying that they were **originally** poor people food. It's cheap to have low-quality pasta with some ready-to-eat sauce, but I wouldn't call that healthy food. Of course I do agree that "the poor" are mostly lazy, but that doesn't change the fact, that quality food cost money. However, I'd change the question from "fast-food" to "junk-food", so it'd cover stuff like frozen pizza.

Comment: @nico - Its because people do not want to eat "poor peoples dishes" we want food that tastes good.  Can we eat mac&Cheese or ramen noodles sure.  But we want more.  We prefer the taste of name brands over generic usually.  We do not want to buy the cheap stuff we want the good stuff.  So comparing the meals we make at home to mcdonalds results in higher cost meals.

Comment: @Chad: spaghetti garlic and oil, pasta alla carbonara (onions, bacon, egg), bean soup, pumpkin pie, minestrone, beef stew, stir fry, roasted chicken (bonus, roast an entire chicken and you can do several different meals with it) and I could go on (see this question on cooking SE for instance). All supertasty, cheap and healthy.

Comment: @nico: sorry, **tasty, cheap and healthy**? you can have any combination of two of these, but not 3 at a time.

Comment: @vartec: I just posted a list of dishes that satisfy all of those 3 conditions. I will concede that *tasty* is subjective, but I consider those dishes all very tasty. And, for sure, all of the above are tastier than anything that comes out of McDonald's... PS: nothing wrong in being lazy and wanting to eat outside, I'm just saying that it is possible to cook good food without spending too much.

Comment: @nico - A spagetti dinner for me and my wife costs around $25 (We do it regularly) I could go cheap but I dont I like GOOD food.  Its over 30 if i make my own sauce instead of Ragu Robusto.  Olive garden spagetti w/meat sauce - $8.99 each with bread sticks and soup.  Throw in $2 each for drink and its 11.99.  OG is not even a fast food restraunt.

Comment: @Chad: $25 for 2? Well, prices must be incredibly high around your parts! For me (buying good stuff in small local shops, not supermarkets, prices in euro): 1Kg spaghetti Barilla 1.50 - peeled tomatoes (500g) 2 - minced pork/veal 3/4 (500g) - add 1 or 2 euros for an onion, a carrot, some celery a bit of olive oil and a glass of wine for the ragu... you have spent less than 10 euros and can eat in 4 people. Let's say you're very hungry and you eat 1 kg of pasta in 2, that's still cheaper than a fast food. Plus I find cooking very relaxing :)

Comment: And, another link: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/394/good-cheap-easy-to-make-food-that-can-be-reheated

Comment: @nico - I did not say you couldnt. I said we do not. And I can get 2 meals at McD's for under 10euro. It wont be good for your or even fill as much but its a meal and its less than 10 euro and you are streching to get what you want for that price. And it does not include bread or drink. The markets common in europe are not really common in the US most places are lucky to have more than the local walmart to shop at. We get farmers markets on weekends but lately they are not cheap like they used to be.

Comment: @nico: first of all, it doesn't matter if you can feed 4 ppl if you only need food for one. It's €10 assuming that you don't add any fresh herbs, fresh garlic, you're not using fresh tomatoes etc. And even if, you still can get lot more junk-food for 10€. That's like 5 big kebabs, or 5 king deal menus from BK (that's cheesburger, small fries and small drink for €1.99), or 4-6 crapy frozen pizzas. Obviously it's not healthy, not very tasty, but what it is, is dirt cheap.

Comment: @nico: I really need to move to Europe!  1kg of decent pasta (Barilla, De Cecco, *&c.*) at my supermarket is ~US$7.  Decent quality tomatoes are ~$10/kg.  Thanks to ridiculous taxes in my state, a palatable bottle of table wine is at least $10.

Comment: @ESultanik - I didnt think of that I am paying $2.5 for 8 oz of pasta thats over $10 for a kg.

Comment: @ES: Barilla is Italian, so for you it's product imported from overseas, so price includes shipping cost and import taxes. Tomatoes are good example though, frikin' expensive. It's something like €1/kg here.

Comment: @vartec: Barilla isn't commonly imported into the US; [they have a factory in Iowa](http://wikimapia.org/609179/Barilla-Factory).

Comment: @ES: good point, then I don't see why it'd be so expensive either.

Comment: This comment thread making me hungry! I think it shows that the question needs some more definition to help people answer it, but can we please take that to chat, and then update the question with the resolution?

Comment: @BlueWhale: `As for not enough time to prepare meals, that seems hard to believe... not enough time for 15 or 20 minutes?` you don't seem to be running your own house; cooking yourself also means more trips to grocery (takes 2 hour/week for 2 trips/week) and cleaning up utensils (20 minutes/day = 140 minutes/week). And no decent home-cooked food can be prepared in 20 minutes, with that much time you get to unfreeze frozen prepacked food, that's all. To cook raw meat using pressure cooker takes 15-20 minutes not including preparing other ingredient which takes another 15-30 minutes.

Comment: @BlueWhale: In my experience, cooking proper food usually takes about 1 hour even with pressure cooker, instant spices, and other shortcuts (without them, it can easily take 3 hour). All that time can be spent doing other stuffs instead, say making money, studying/learning new skills, or relaxing (i.e. [opportunity cost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_cost)). If nobody in the house enjoys or cook well anyway (as is common in 1- or 2- person house), then suddenly fast food or cheap takeaway can be an appealing option.

Comment: @Lie: If we say it takes 15 minutes more to cook than to pop down to the local McBurger, that adds some $10-$20 to the price since I can't spend that time making money. Now that's not valid if you have a fixed salary, which most people do. But for independent people like me, it is.

Answer (score 19):

> How could that be cheaper than cooking for yourself?

Alternative to fast-food is buying fresh ingredients and preparing food yourself. Problem is that fresh produce **retail** price is constantly growing due to growing margins, rather than on par with underlying producer's price. This phenomenon is not local to any country, it has been observed in the US, throughout Europe, in Australia and New Zealand. It's attributed to super/hyper-market chains having too much influence over prices on both ends of the chain (producers and end-clients).

Some papers and articles covering the subject:
[Thomas Worth *The F.o.b.-Retail Price Relationship
For Selected Fresh Vegetables*](http://www.ers.usda.gov/briefing/vegetables/vegpdf/FOBRetailPriceVeg.pdf) (bit outdated)

> The f.o.b. [Free-on-board shipping-point prices] and retail price trends are rising for all of the
> selected commodities. Prices for the second time period,
> 1980-99, are presented in figure B-1. The solid lines in the
> graphs represent a two-year moving average for retail and
> for f.o.b. prices. Retail prices consistently rise during this
> time period. Except for potatoes, f.o.b. prices rise consistently,
> albeit modestly, as well. **The retail-f.o.b. margin
> increases for all of the commodities.**

[Timothy J. Richards and Paul M. Patterson, *Competition in Fresh Produce
Markets,
An Empirical Analysis of Marketing
Channel Performance*](http://agecon.ucdavis.edu/people/faculty/roberta-cook/docs/Articles/PattersonRichERS03.pdf)

> Fresh produce growers/shippers believe that consolidations in grocery retailing may
> empower retailers to act less competitively. This study evaluates the extent to which
> retailers exercise market power in buying from growers and selling to consumers. Sales
> data for retail chains in six U.S. metropolitan markets are used along with data on
> grower prices for an analysis on apples, grapes, oranges, and grapefruit. **The evidence
> varies by commodity, but does consistently point to the exercise of market power by
> retailers in consumer sales;** less support is found on buying market power. Market power
> varies over time and with produce volume.

News article [*"Rising costs force fresh fruit and vegetables off the table"*](http://www.perthnow.com.au/money/rising-costs-force-fresh-fruit-and-vegetables-off-the-table/story-e6frg2uc-1226073894308)

> **The number of people who say they have been forced to skip fresh fruit and vegetables because of skyrocketing prices has jumped from 6 to 30 per cent in six years.** And retailers have been accused of profiteering from this year's flood and cyclone disasters, hitting shoppers with 300 per cent mark-ups.
>
> In one case, a farmer found pineapples being sold at a small fruit shop for 14 times the price paid to growers for the same produce.

---

> When you buy fast food, you are paying for labor, corporate overhead, restaurant space, etc.

The same can be said about supermarkets. You are also paying for the produce that will go to the dumpster at closing time. Much less so in case of fast food establishments, which use mostly processed and/or refrigerated products and have limited variety.

Comment: You effectively argued the position and you didnt even touch on the Economy of scale.  The base costs are less because they buy more and have a limited selection.  Supermarkets conviently have a huge variety but limited quantity of each.  The variety that mcdonalds purchases fits on around 2 printed sheets.  They just buy alot of all of it.

Comment: I’m not convinced. Buying *healthy*, tasty food may be (well, it is!) expensive. But bulk buying at a grocers is vastly cheaper than eating fast food and I know several people who do this, and who say that they cannot afford fast food. In fact, that’s a very simple calculation. Of course, this may vary extremely from country to country and I suspect that’s part of the explanation here.

Comment: @Konrad: indeed it seems that in Germany produce is cheaper, still I find that as far as price goes, it cannot compete with all Dr. Oetker crap.

Comment: well said, vartec. Same here in the Netherlands. Since switching from mostly processed to all fresh foods a few months ago my grocery bill has gone up almost 50%, and I'm eating less (because the food is more nutritious and filling) so per volume/weight the difference is even greater. Another less extreme example is baking your own bread vs buying it in the shop. In shop, expect to pay 1.50-2.50. To bak your own, expect to pay at least 3.50-4.50 per loaf.

Comment: @jw: yeah, I'm used to Dutch prices, but Konrad according to his profile is located in Berlin. It surprised how much cheaper is it there, especially the meat.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer really answers the question. This answer discusses how grocer prices are changing over time (ok), but it's missing a direct comparison between grocer prices and fast food prices at a fixed point in time.

Answer (score 9):

The price of healthy and specially fresh products is always on the rise, but as of 2011 I still cook my -healthy- food myself for considerably less than a Mac Menu or equivalent costs.

There are entire websites dedicated to the subject of budget healthy cooking, but in my opinion the most important and universally applicable tips regardless of the country are:

- Buy bulk, like one per month and planning beforehand what you are going to buy (make a list)
- Eat everything. It's surprising how much food gets thrown away. Don't let that yoghurt expire, and if you make too much rice for luch, eat it for dinner. The point is to realize the exact quantity of everything you need, which in my experience is always far less than expected, so you can afford more money on your next shopping.

In the countries where I lived (Ireland, France, Spain, Italy) I also saved **a lot** of money by buying at local shops, where you usually get discounts for being a good client, and where you might get to know even the actual producers/fishers. I don't know if this applies elsewhere.

I also find the quality of frozen-at-sea fish excellent for a fraction of the price.

**UPDATED: References**

- [How to Feed Your Whole Family a Healthy Balanced Diet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1905862156) (Gil Holcombe): A very detailed guide including all the tips I comment here and many more.
- [Once-a-month cooking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805418350) (Mary Beth Lagerborg and Mimi Wilson): about the quality of frozen fish and food in general.

Comment: You have argued that there are ways of cooking both healthfully and inexpensively, however, that does not answer [BlueWhale](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/3278/bluewhale)'s original question of whether or not that can be *cheaper* than fast food.  I think you need to provide evidence to the fact that these methods can in fact be less expensive than buying fast food in the same location.

Comment: How can you buy **fresh** produce, if only shopping once per month? Eating canned, processed food isn't exactly most healthy.

Answer (score 3):

First, I want to elaborate a bit on the economics behind some of this.  As many people already mentioned, this is going to vary greatly from country to country.  Why?  Well, raw commodity prices are very volatile, due to varying government subsidies, differences in climate, extreme climatic events, supply chains, *&c.*  The supermarket industry in the US is extremely competitive.  SuperValu, for example, is a giant corporation that [owns many supermarket chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_supermarket_chains_in_the_United_States).  They are [lucky to eek away a 1.5% profit margin](http://ycharts.com/companies/SVU/profit_margin).  (In other words, at most 1.5% of their gross income is a profit.)  That means they could lower their prices at most ~1.5% without taking a loss.  Bulk sellers like [Costco](http://ycharts.com/companies/COST/profit_margin) and even the giant [Wal-Mart](http://ycharts.com/companies/WMT/profit_margin) are lucky to reach 3%.  Successful fast food restaurants like McDonalds, on the other hand, easily reach [a profit margin of 20%](http://ycharts.com/companies/MCD/profit_margin).  That means, in effect, McDonalds could reduce their prices by ~20% and still stay afloat.

Why is this?  One major reason is that companies like McDonalds can and do have complete [vertical integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_integration) of their supply chains: McDonalds raises their own cattle, grows their own potatoes, transports their own raw ingredients, and largely owns the real estate of their restaurants.  In fact, McDonalds even [makes a profit off of leasing their real estate to McDonalds franchises](http://money.howstuffworks.com/mcdonalds2.htm).  That flexibility is partially one reason why **[a Big Mac will be worth the equivalent of US$10 in Brazil while the same Big Mac will be worth US$1.50 in Croatia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Mac_Index)**.  Supermarkets don't really have much opportunity for vertical integration unless they actually buy and operate their farms and suppliers.

**Now, to the question of whether eating fast food is cheaper.**  As [I mentioned in my answer to the food deserts question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4927/are-food-deserts-a-real-phenomenon/4931#4931), at least in the US there is a definitive link between poverty, obesity, and lack of proximity to a supermarket.  There was also [a study in the UK that discovered a correlation between the density of fast food restaurants and poverty](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.amepre.2005.06.011):

> Statistically significant positive associations were found between neighborhood deprivation [*i.e.*, poverty] and the mean number of McDonald’s outlets per 1000 people for Scotland (p<0.001), England (p<0.001), and both countries combined (p<0.001). These associations were broadly linear with greater mean numbers of outlets per 1000 people occurring as deprivation levels increased.

**Update**: I re-wrote the following paragraph to include a rigorous argument.

Let's have some fun now and look at the [Consumer Price Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_price_index) (CPI), which estimates average expenditures for various goods over a month.  [The current CPI in the US for food and beverages is $227.5](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=USA%20consumer%20price%20index) (meaning that the average consumer spends $227.5 per month on food and beverages).  Now let's assume that the cost of non-fast-food is cheaper than eating fast food and proceed with a proof by contradiction.  Under this assumption, the CPI of $227.5 is obviously a lower bound on the amount one would spend if one only ate fast food (since the CPI includes all types of food-related expenditures).  This equates to about $8 per day.  [In 2008, the average price of a Big Mac in the US was $3.57](http://www.economist.com/node/11793125?story_id=11793125), and it is certainly possible for one to subsist off of two Big Macs per day.  That's especially true since a Big Mac is one of the more expensive items on the McDonalds menu.  A [McDouble](http://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en/food/full_menu/sandwiches/mcdouble.html), for example, costs only $1.  This is a contradiction, *i.e.*, we have shown that it is in fact possible to live off of less than $8 a day of fast food, thus breaking the lower bound and **invalidating our assumption that eating non-fast-food is cheaper than eating fast food**.∎

This suggests that it is at least plausible that eating fast food could be cheaper than grocery shopping in the US.  This is of course under some tenuous assumptions, but one can't really definitively answer your question without actually studying the average cost of groceries.

Comment: "definitive link between poverty, obesity, and lack of proximity to a supermarket." - but that doesn't however prove causality.

Comment: @vartec: True, but it does support the argument that poor people are more likely to have a bad diet.

Comment: I don't think that last paragraph is a very rigorous argument. You can live on peanut butter and bread cheaper than you can live on McDoubles ($4 or $5 total for a jar of PB and a loaf of bread), but nobody really does either one, so it doesn't factor into the CPI.

Comment: @mmyers: I'm not sure I understand your argument.  The fact that relatively few people live off of PB sandwiches is exactly the point.  Also, peanut butter is not a complete protein; [it lacks some of the essential amino acids required for life](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/legumes-and-legume-products/4366/2).  Therefore, one could likely not live off of PB&Bread alone.

Comment: I think that makes us even then. :) I guess I don't understand what your argument is proving. Sure, you can buy lobsters and steak in a grocery store and it will cost more than fast food. Why is that relevant? I think the question is for an equivalent diet... or something. It's really hard to pin down exactly what it's asking.

Comment: @mmyers: Good point.  Basically, my argument is saying that it is possible to live off fast food for less than the average US consumer spends on groceries.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the logic in your last paragraph, either. Are you saying that, if you assume that cost of groceries < fast food, then the monthly cost of an exclusively fast-food diet would be higher than the CPI since the CPI consists of an average of groceries and fast-food combined? If so, then doesn't that logic fail since the CPI isn't *only* fast-food+groceries (i.e. it includes unnecessary snacking, fine and social dining, and other "luxury" spending)?

Comment: @Beofett: That's basically the logic.  You do make a good point though: It's really saying that it is possible to live off fast food for less than the average US consumer spends on all food.  I'll edit my answer to make that clear.

Comment: This is very localised: in central Europe, for example, a Big Mac is more expensive. Furthermore, while the caloric intake may strictly be enough to feed on two Big Macs per day, I doubt that this is in fact possible over long stretches of time; the body simply craves *food*, not just calories. And it is very much possible to bulk buy for an average daily price of less than that of two Big Macs here.

Comment: "Also, peanut butter is not a complete protein; it lacks some of the essential amino acids required for life. Therefore, one could likely not live off of PB&Bread alone." - Required for protein (not required for life). But combining with bread supplies the missing amino acids: so PB *and bread* is 'complete': it's an example of the canonical 'legume and grain', like 'rice and peas'. Or 'love and lentils'. :)

Comment: @ChrisW: Good point.

Comment: The CPI is broken down by meals at home, and meals prepared commercially outside the home. Spending is about the same 50%/50%, but according to the NHIS, the average american eats out less than 3 meals a week. Unfortunately, the CPI doesn't breakdown total meals inside and outside the home, for that You will need the NHIS which says that less than half consumed more than 3+ [meals per week]  (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14715218)

Comment: The detailed CPI report is here. http://www.bls.gov/cpi/cpid1203.pdf

Answer (score 3):

This is going to be a very subjective question, even more so depending upon where in the world you are and what your motivations are. Thus, for the purposes of this answer, I am going to assume that it is for someone living in the United States and is concerned with saving "real money" (i.e. what is in their wallet) versus any subjective costs due to time invested in cooking or other time invested in preparing meals.

First, we need to look at this question from the standpoint of day to day meals. While some of the other answers and their comments cite a [fairly expenditure for foodstuffs](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/5454/6629), I am going to approach this from the standpoint of someone that is going to make a dedicated effort to save as much money on their meals as possible. Thus, they will be looking for meals that are inexpensive, filling, nutritional, and generate leftovers. The leftovers might be a significant point that is lost in some of the other answers as a meal that costs $5 for the ingredients but generates 8 servings has a cost of $0.625 per serving which automatically puts it under the $1 per serving that some fast food restaurants offer on their "Dollar Menu". Finding such recipes is [fairly easy](http://www.allyou.com/food/supercheap-meals/cheap-recipes-00411000070180/page22.html), although inflation and availability of ingredients may affect costs over time.

If you search online you can find a number of anecdotal and other articles (["How I Eat for a Month with Twenty Dollars"](http://voices.yahoo.com/how-eat-month-twenty-dollars-431349.html), "[Eating Well On $1 A Day](http://www.grocerycouponguide.com/articles/eating-well-on-1-a-day/)", "[How To Live (Comfortably) on $36 A Month For Food](http://andrewhy.de/how-to-live-comfortably-on-36-a-month-for-food/)") that demonstrate that living on a highly limited food budget is possible with a bit of creativity although a learning curve is involved. If we compare this to the aforementioned dollar menus and assume that people would at least two meals ($2 a day) for an average of 30 days gives us a budget of around $60 dollars. However, if you examine the [nutrition information](http://nutrition.mcdonalds.com/getnutrition/nutritionfacts.pdf) available from McDonald's you will note that most Dollar Menu items are not high in calories and thus someone may be tempted to order more due to hunger and the perceived "low cost." Once this starts to occur, the daily cost of eating fast food is going to go up high than the aforementioned $60 a month which could bring it well in the range of the low estimated average of [$112.25 per person, per month back in the 2003 - 2004 time frame](http://www.personalfinanceanalyst.com/the-average-cost-of-groceries-per-person-best-guesses/). Even factoring inflation and other rising costs, it is not hard to see how purchasing off the Dollar Menu can bring you within the lower average cost for a single person to eat.

Next, to approach the question from the standpoint of long term costs such as heath, it is generally accepted that there is a clear connection between [fast food and obesity](http://emlab.berkeley.edu/~sdellavi/wp/fastfoodJan09.pdf). Since obesity is connected to [higher health care costs](http://www.news.cornell.edu/stories/April12/ObesityCosts.html), we can likely conclude that over the long run any short term savings would likely be wiped out by long term expenses. Although depending upon someones income level, that burden might be bore by the state as opposed to the individual.

Finally, a new study by the UDSA has shown that the [cost of food really depends upon how you measure it](http://www.ers.usda.gov/publications/eib-economic-information-bulletin/eib96.aspx). [CNN summarized things as follows](http://thechart.blogs.cnn.com/2012/05/17/usda-healthy-food-isnt-really-more-expensive/):

> For instance, take a chocolate glazed donut. Each donut is probably
>   about 240 calories, and you could probably eat two or three of them
>   with no problem (and just a teensy bit of guilt). Then take a banana
>   with about 105 calories.
>
> If these two cost the same, the banana is more expensive per each
>   calorie eaten. But you’ll probably only eat one and feel a lot fuller
>   afterward, Carlson said. That makes it cheaper per edible gram and per
>   the average portion.

Answer (score 1):

In the affluent world, when you cook for yourself, the cost of time forgone is very large, because hourly wages are very high (relative to the poorer parts of the world).

Take the US. Even if you make [the minimum wage ($7.25/hr)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_wage_in_the_United_States#Federal_minimum_wage), if it takes you 20 more minutes to prepare and cook your own food (and then clean up after and all that) as compared to getting something from McDonald's, that's $2.42 in wages you've forgone. With that money you could get two items from the dollar menu ([two McChickens say](http://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en/food/meal_bundles/dollar_menu.html)) and still have change leftover. And of course I haven't even counted the cost of your groceries, wear-and-tear on your cooking equipment, utilities, etc. that go towards making your own meal.

Comment: Welcome to Skeptics! This Q&A site requires people to provide references in their answers. For more information, have a look at the tour: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tour . Thanks!

Comment: Aight, I added a link for the US minimum wage and a link to McDonald's dollar menu. Hopefully that makes my answer look more credible.